# Two sequences of operators on Hilbert Space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $H$ is some Hilbert Space, and $a_n,b_n \in B(H)$ is sequences of some operators on it. We know, that $a_n  b_n$ converges to $v$ by norm. We also know, that all $b_n a_n$ are strictly positive.  Does it imply that $b_n a_n$ converges by norm to some element?